# Generated typescript appears redundant, but I bet it's not

Tags: javascript, typescript, nswag

NSwag generates typescript classes with properties defined like this:

```
export class Foo {
  id?: number | undefined;
}
```

I know `?` means the `id` property is optional. I would expect these property definitions to be effectively the same as the above:

```
id?: number
id: number | undefined
```

What are the differences between these definitions? Why might NSwag have chosen the first?

Comment: It's the difference between `{ id: undefined }` and `{}`. Marking a property as optional means it can be left out of the object.

Comment: Pretty much implicit `undefined` vs explicit `undefined`, you get both here.

Comment: TypeScript has a `--strictNullChecks` flag, which when enabled would make `id?: number` automatically have the explicit type `number | undefined`. You all have this flag set to `true` right? ;)

Comment: Hey there, an accepted answer (even if it's not mine) or request for more details would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Marking a property with `?` indicates it may or may not be *declared* on the object. Giving it a possible type of `undefined` says that even if it is declared, it may not have a value.

`id?: number` Says that if the property is declared on the object, it will have numerical value.

`id: number | undefined` Says the property is declared but may either be a number or have no defined value.

`id?: number | undefined` Says the property may or may not be declared, and even if it is declared, may be a number or have no defined value.

You could have the object `obj = {id: undefined}`, where `id` is still present but has no value, or you could have `obj = {}` where `id` is undeclared on the object. In either case `typeof obj.id === 'undefined'` would be true, but only in the first would `id` be an enumerable key of the object.

However, the Typescript compiler seems to be somewhat loose with these specifics in my experimentation. Even in the 3rd case, it seems to assume if a property is declared it is also defined.

To address the root of your question, it is not redundant, but indicates specific object properties. When consuming a class property marked with `?` and `undefined`, you cannot assume that just because it is declared that it has a value. The best way to check it's value would be checking for a numerical type: `typeof obj.id === 'number'`, as a truthy check on a number is never a good idea (`0 == false`). Simply iterating through the object (`for i in obj`) or checking for a property on the object (`if('id' in obj)`) would also be unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this snippet to see the difference:

```
interface Foo {
    id?: number | undefined;
}

function giveMeFoo(foo: Foo): void {
    if ("id" in foo) {
        // Here, foo.id has type: number | undefined
    }
    if (foo.id) {
        // Here, foo.id has type: number
    }
}

interface Bar {
    id?: number;
}

function giveMeBar(bar: Bar): void {
    if ("id" in bar) {
        // Here, bar.id has type: number
    }
    if (bar.id) {
        // Here, bar.id has type: number
    }
}
```

Basically, a optional property (using `?`) means that the property may not exist on the object, but if it does, it has the type listed. If you are merely checking for the existence of the property (and not its truthyness), then the result can still be undefined.

So I'm guessing the reason NSwag produced that definition is because not only may the property `id` be missing from the object, but even if the object has the `id` property, it may be explicitly set to `undefined`.

Comment: Truthy checks on possible numbers are not a good idea as `0 == false`.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark will make that parameter optional so passing {} to something that expects a Foo object wouldn't break in the TS compiler. If it wasn't optional and could be undefined, {} would cause a type error while {id} wouldn't.